# AngularFire 0.5 $on 'loaded' not firing correctly

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am having some troubles with the $on method in AngularFire 0.5 I am using the following route /assets/:assetCollection/:assetId

The problem is that when I go from /assets/:assetCollection to /assets/:assetCollection/:assetId the data is loaded from Firebase (I can see it in Batarang) but the $on('loaded', function(){}) never fires.

The Routes:

```
angular.module('imageGrid',
  ['imageGrid.config', 'imageGrid.filters', 'imageGrid.services', 'imageGrid.directives', 'imageGrid.controllers', 'ngRoute', 'firebase']
)

// configure views; note the authRequired parameter for authenticated pages
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/assets/:assetCollection', {
    authRequired: true,
    templateUrl: 'partials/assets.html',
    controller: 'AssetsCtrl'
  })

  .when('/assets/:assetCollection/:assetId', {
    authRequired: true,
    templateUrl: 'partials/asset-detail.html',
    controller: 'AssetDetailCtrl'
  })

  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/assets/all' });
}])
```

The Controllers:

```
.controller('AssetsCtrl',
  ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$firebase', 'FBURL',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $firebase, FBURL) {
    // load data from firebase
    var refAssets = new Firebase(FBURL).child('/assets');
    $scope.assets = $firebase(refAssets);

    $scope.assetCollection = $routeParams.assetCollection;
    $scope.pagetitle.pagename = 'Assets in category: ' + $scope.assetCollection;
}])

.controller('AssetDetailCtrl',
  ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$routeParams', '$firebase', 'FBURL',
  function($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, $firebase, FBURL) {
    $scope.validAsset = undefined;
    $scope.pagetitle.pagename = "Loading Asset...";
    $scope.assetId = $routeParams.assetId;
    $scope.assetCollection = $routeParams.assetCollection;

    // Load data from firebase
    var refAsset = new Firebase(FBURL).child('/assets/' + $scope.assetId);
    $scope.asset = $firebase(refAsset);

    // when data is loaded check validity of the route
    $scope.asset.$on('loaded', function(value) {
      console.log('data loaded');
      if (value !== null) {
        checkRoute(value.name, value.collections);
      } else {
        checkRoute(null);
      }
    });

    var checkRoute = function(name, collections) {
      var isValid = function(assetCollections) {
        var currentCollection = $scope.assetCollection;
        /* Check validity of asset based on the following rules
         * - When collection route is 'all' asset valid
         * - When assets collection array contains the collection route asset is valid
         * - Otherwise assume asset is invalid
         */
        if (currentCollection === 'all') {
          return true;
        } else if (assetCollections !== undefined) {
          if (assetCollections.indexOf(currentCollection) >= 0) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      };

      var isValidResponse = false;
      // when data is loaded check the validity of the route
      if (name !== null) {
        isValidResponse = isValid(collections);
      }
      // Linked to ng-if on detail page to show asset detail or invalid route page
      $scope.validAsset = isValidResponse;
      // Set controller specific page title based on validity of asset route
      if(isValidResponse) {
        $scope.pagetitle.pagename = name;
      } else {
        $scope.pagetitle.pagename = 'ERROR: Asset does not exist';
      }
      $scope.$apply();
    };
}])
```

It also doesn't fire when the :assetCollection route param is changed when in the AssetsDetailCtrl. I would not expect it to but I thought it may be worth mentioning.

I have also tried wrapping the load in a function but it did not work either

```
var loadAsset = function() {
  // Load data from firebase
  var refAsset = new Firebase(FBURL).child('/assets/' + $scope.assetId);
  $scope.asset = $firebase(refAsset);

  // when data is loaded check validity of the route
  $scope.asset.$on('loaded', function(value) {
    console.log('data loaded');
    if (value !== null) {
      checkRoute(value.name, value.collections);
    } else {
      checkRoute(null);
    }
  });
};

$scope.$watch('assetCollection', loadAsset);
```

All the functionality works as expected if the page is refreshed after the route change.
Why is it that the $on method isn't firing after the route change.

Any advise would be much appreciated.

For a full code sample here is my repo
https://github.com/ThisIsMeh/imagegrid

Comment: Where do you broadcast or emit "loaded" event?

Comment: It is a built in event in AngularFire 0.5

loaded: The event is triggered exactly once, when the initial data is received from Firebase.

http://angularfire.com/documentation.html

Comment: The loaded event is only fired once, when the initial data is loaded. On a route change, the data isn't downloaded again from Firebase but instead served up from the cache. Is the 'changed' event Firing?

Comment: Even when the route changes controllers? I added a change event to the AssetDetailCtrl, it fires 12 times and value is undefined. $scope.asset.$on('change', function(value) {})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope is directly assessable in the 'change' event

```
$scope.asset.$on('change', function() {
  var asset = $scope.asset;
  if (asset.name !== null) {
    checkRoute(asset.name, asset.collections);
  } else {
    checkRoute(null);
  }
});
```

Simple enough